# Tar archive to remote ftp

Tags: curl, ftp, tar

I have big data for backup (50 GB). I don't want to create the tar archive to hdd. I have a ssd.

I want upload the tar file simultaneous to a remote ftp.

But this code doesn't work. I got an error meesage: "Uploading to a URL without a file name!"

```
tar czf - /home/ | curl -u username:password ftp://ftp.site.com/ -T -
```

Comment: try giving a target file name, e.g. ftp://ftp.site.com/foo.tar

Answer (score 0):

`ftp` also available:

```
tar Jcpvf - / | ftp -u ftp://user:password@example.com/full.backup.tar.xz -
```

it creates a stream to `stdout` and pass it to the ftp server without creating file. `ftp` is an usual ftp client on any *nix/BSD system.